# Background-image is repating (Position absolute)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have som issues I set a background-image on div, and this div have position absolute. The problem is my background-image is repeating, I have tried 
to set background-image to no-repeat but its not working.
[enter image description here][1]

Image-repeating:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v1Cw.png
 the problem is on mobile device.

```js
 setTimeout(function () {
        var sec3Cont = document.getElementById('sectionThreeContent');
        sec3Cont.parentElement.style.height = sec3Cont.offsetHeight + 'px';
        sec3Cont.parentElement.parentElement.style.height = sec3Cont.offsetHeight + 'px';

        var sec4Cont = document.getElementById('sectionFourContainer');
        sec4Cont.parentElement.style.height = sec4Cont.offsetHeight + 'px';
        sec4Cont.parentElement.parentElement.style.height = sec4Cont.offsetHeight + 'px';

        var sec5Cont = document.getElementById('sectionFiveConatiner');
        sec5Cont.parentElement.style.height = sec5Cont.offsetHeight + 'px';
        sec5Cont.parentElement.parentElement.style.height = sec5Cont.offsetHeight + 'px';

        var sec6Cont = document.getElementById('sectionSixContainer');
        sec6Cont.parentElement.style.height = sec6Cont.offsetHeight + 'px';
        sec6Cont.parentElement.parentElement.style.height = sec6Cont.offsetHeight + 'px';
    }, 1000);

    $(function () {
        var bgBlack = "url(/WicconDeisgn/bgblack.jpg)";
        var bgGrey = "url(/WicconDeisgn/bggrey.jpg)";

        function checkScroll() {
            var positionAbsolute = true;

            var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
            var secTwo = $("#sectionTwo").offset().top;
            var secThree = $("#sectionThree").offset().top;
            var secFour = $("#sectionFour").offset().top;
            var secFive = $("#sectionFive").offset().top;
            var secSix = $("#sectionSix").offset().top;

            var obj3 = document.getElementById('sectionThree');
            var screenDiff3 = obj3.offsetHeight - screen.availHeight;

            var obj4 = document.getElementById('sectionFour');
            var screenDiff4 = obj4.offsetHeight - screen.availHeight;

            var obj5 = document.getElementById('sectionFive');
            var screenDiff5 = obj5.offsetHeight - screen.availHeight;

            if (scrollPos < secTwo) {
                $(".child").css("position", "");
                positionAbsolute = false;
            }
            if (scrollPos >= secTwo) {
                $(".child").css("position", "absolute");
                $("#sectionTwo").children(".parent").children(".navigationDesktop").children(".navbar").css("background-image", bgGrey);
                positionAbsolute = true;
            }
            if (scrollPos >= (secThree + (screenDiff3))) {
                $(".child").css("position", "");
                $("#sectionThree").children(".parent").children(".navigationDesktop").children(".navbar").css("background-image", bgGrey);
                positionAbsolute = false;
            }
            if (scrollPos >= secFour) {
                $(".child").css("position", "absolute");
                $("#sectionFour").children(".parent").children(".navigationDesktop").children(".navbar").css("background-image", bgBlack);
                positionAbsolute = true;
            }
            if (scrollPos >= (secFive + screenDiff5)) {
                $(".child").css("position", "");
                $("#sectionFive").children(".parent").children(".navigationDesktop").children(".navbar").css("background-image", bgGrey);
                positionAbsolute = false;
            }
            if (scrollPos >= secSix) {
                $(".child").css("position", "absolute");
                $("#sectionSix").children(".parent").children(".navigationDesktop").children(".navbar").css("background-image", bgBlack);
                positionAbsolute = true;
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(checkScroll);
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(checkScroll);
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    /*overflow: auto;*/
    /*-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;*/
    /*-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 100%);*/
}

.fullpage {
    height: 100%;
}

.section {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.parent {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0, auto, auto, 0);
    
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .parent {
        -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 100%);
         
    }
}

.child {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

p span {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Lato Semibold',sans-serif;
    font-size: 3.125rem;
    border: solid #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
}

#arrow_one, #arrow_two {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.row-pt {
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.overflow-text {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#sec3Text {
margin:0;
}

#sectionFour{
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
}

.center-row {
    top: 30%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.topBottom {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.container-bottom-0 {
    bottom: 0;
}

.container-top-0 {
    top: 0;
}

.min-h {
    min-height: 50vw;
}

.square {
    width: 15vw;
    height: 15vw;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #ccc;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: 0.3s linear;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    perspective: 500px;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

    .square .area {
        width: 90%;
        height: 90%;
        left: 5%;
        top: 5%;
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        transform: translateZ(3em);
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

        .square .area .plupp {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 10%;
            height: 10%;
            padding: 4%;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
            border-radius: 3px;
            -webkit-backface-visiblity: hidden;
            transform: translateZ(0);
            position: relative;
        }

            .square .area .plupp:hover {
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
                transform: translateZ(1.5em);
            }

.innerPlupp {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.none {
    visibility: hidden !important;
}

.hover-text-sec-three {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.title_hover:hover {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #1c7ab1;
}

.mainTitle {
    font-family: 'Lato Semibold',sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.mainTitleTwo {
    font-family: 'Lato Regular',sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.1875rem;
}

.wiccon_descriptions {
    font-family: 'Lato Medium',sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    opacity: 0.71 !important;
}
```

```html
  <div class="section" id="sectionThree">
        <div class="container-fluid bgBlack parent">
            <div class="navigationDesktop">
                @Html.Partial("NavigationDesktop")
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid child container-bottom-0" id="sectionThreeContent">
                @*style="background-color:red;"*@
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row h-100 align-items-center row-pt">
                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 order-xl-1 order-lg-1 order-md-1">
                            <img src="@ArticleImgSecThree" class="img-fluid" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                            <a href="@Umbraco.TypedContent(1377).Url" class="hover-text-sec-three">
                                <p class="text-dark"><span class="title_hover">@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("titleSecThree")</span></p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="@Umbraco.TypedContent(1377).Url" class="hover-text-sec-three">
                                <p id="sec3Text" class="wiccon_descriptions text-dark title_hover"> @Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("articleTextSecThree")</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: try with `!important`.

Comment: I have fixed it now, I set  background-attachment:fixed; on background-image. and it works fine! But thanks for the help! :)